# Set URL for captive portal detection

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, network-manager, internet

Is it possible to set a custom URL for captive portal detection in Ubuntu?

Ubuntu uses https://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com by default to check the connection. Is there a way to change this URL, for example to https://your.host.com/another-path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the URL using the `uri` parameter in the NetworkManager config file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Add the following lines there:

```
[connectivity]
uri=https://your.host.com/another-path
```

The important part is that the server must return either the header `X-NetworkManager-Status` with a value of `online` or a body content with `NetworkManager is online`.

You can also set `interval` to set the check interval in seconds and `response` to require a specific string in the check response. For more information see the *CONNECTIVITY SECTION* of the NetworkManager [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html).

After that you have to restart the NetworkManager or reboot your system:

```
# sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score -1):

supplementary for the existing answer, for the most recent ubuntu dists, the command for network-manager restart should be

```
# sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Comment: Interesting, but internet (including WiFi) disappears after this. I had to go to Settings and manually turn everything off/on.